# T-SQL - DateTime Gap Distribution

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Code:

```
DECLARE @SD DATE    = '2017-01-01'
        ,@ED DATE   = '2017-01-07'
        ,@ST TIME   = '08:00:00'
        ,@ET TIME   = '16:00:00';

DECLARE @DT_T TABLE (SDT DATETIME, EDT DATETIME)
```

Goal:
To combine Start/End Date and Start/End Time (@SD/@ED and @ST/@ET) and create a table with gap intervals between StartDateTime and EndDateTime as shown in the desired output below.

Desired Output

```
/* @DT_T Data
SDT                         EDT
2017-01-01 08:00:00         2017-01-01 16:00:00
2017-01-02 08:00:00         2017-01-02 16:00:00
2017-01-03 08:00:00         2017-01-03 16:00:00
2017-01-04 08:00:00         2017-01-04 16:00:00
2017-01-05 08:00:00         2017-01-05 16:00:00
2017-01-06 08:00:00         2017-01-06 16:00:00
2017-01-07 08:00:00         2017-01-07 16:00:00
*/
```

I'm trying with the numbers table but so far not getting anywhere close.

Comment: I don't see any code besides your declare statements. But you should just be able to add 1 day to the `@SD` until you `=` the `@ED`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? rextester: http://rextester.com/ULTV27021

```
declare @sd date    = '2017-01-01'
        ,@ed date   = '2017-01-07'
        ,@st_hour int = 8
        ,@et_hour int = 16;

declare @dt_t table (sdt datetime, edt datetime);

;with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
, d as (
  select 
      sdt=dateadd(hour,@st_hour,convert(datetime,dateadd(day, row_number() over (order by (select 1)) -1,@sd)))
    , edt=dateadd(hour,@et_hour,convert(datetime,dateadd(day, row_number() over (order by (select 1)) -1,@sd)))
    from         n as deka
      cross join n as hecto
      cross join n as kilo     /* 2.73 years */
      --cross join n as [10k]    /* 27.3 years */
)
insert into @dt_t (sdt,edt)
  select top (datediff(day,@sd,@ed)+1)
      sdt
    , edt
    from d
    order by sdt;

select * from @dt_t
```

**note:** rextester's default output formatting for dates is dd.MM.yyyy

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Should get what you want.

```
DECLARE @SD DATE    = '2017-01-01'
        ,@ED DATE   = '2017-01-07'
        ,@ST TIME   = '08:00:00'
        ,@ET TIME   = '16:00:00';

DECLARE @DT_T TABLE (SDT DATETIME, EDT DATETIME)

Declare @i int = 0

While (@SD < @ED)
Begin
    Insert Into @DT_T(SDT, EDT)
    Select Cast(Convert(varchar(10),DateAdd(Day,@i,@SD),21) + ' ' + Convert(varchar(8),@ST,21) as datetime), Cast(Convert(varchar(10),DateAdd(Day,@i,@SD),21) + ' ' + Convert(varchar(10),@ET,21) as DateTime)  
    Set @i = @i + 1     
    IF (DateAdd(Day,@i,@SD) = @ED)      
        Break
    Else
        Continue
END
Insert Into @DT_T(SDT, EDT)
Select Cast(Convert(varchar(10),@ED,21) + ' ' + Convert(varchar(8),@ST,21) as datetime), Cast(Convert(varchar(10),@ED,21) + ' ' + Convert(varchar(10),@ET,21) as DateTime)

Select SDT, EDT From @DT_T
```

Comment: Why use a loop when you can use a set based operation? [Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 1 - Aaron Bertrand - 2013-01-16](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)

Comment: Good point. This was the first thought and I was trying to keep it simple for the most part. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Use the next approach

1. use [datediff](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) function for inserting the rows between the 2
       ranges.
2. update only the time in datetime values.

**Demo:-**

```
DECLARE @SD DATE    = '2017-01-01'
        ,@ED DATE   = '2017-01-07'
        ,@ST TIME   = '08:00:00'
        ,@ET TIME   = '16:00:00';

DECLARE @DT_T TABLE (SDT DATETIME, EDT DATETIME)
DECLARE @start int

set @start = 0
while @start <= datediff(day,@SD,@ED)
begin
    insert into @DT_T values
                            (   dateadd(day,@start, @SD)  , 
                                dateadd(day,@start, @SD))  

    set @start = @start + 1
end

UPDATE @DT_T 
SET SDT = DATEADD(HOUR, 8, CAST(CAST(SDT AS DATE) AS DATETIME)) ,
    EDT = DATEADD(HOUR, 16, CAST(CAST(EDT AS DATE) AS DATETIME))

select * from @DT_T
```

**Result:-**

[image]

Comment: Why use a loop when you can use a set based operation? [Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 1 - Aaron Bertrand - 2013-01-16](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)

Answer (score 1):

I'll often use a TVF to create dynamic date/time ranges.  A tally table would do the trick as well.  The UDF can be faster than a recursive CTE and is parameter driven.  You supply the date range, DatePart and Increment.  For Example:

```
Declare @D1 datetime = '2017-01-01'
Declare @D2 datetime = '2017-01-07'
Declare @T1 datetime = '08:00'

Select RetSeq
      ,STD = RetVal
      ,EDT = DateAdd(HOUR,8,RetVal)
 From [dbo].[udf-Range-Date](@D1+@T1,@D2+@T1,'DD',1)
```

Returns

[image]

The UDF if needed

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Range-Date] (@R1 datetime,@R2 datetime,@Part varchar(10),@Incr int)
Returns Table
Return (
    with cte0(M)   As (Select 1+Case @Part When 'YY' then DateDiff(YY,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'QQ' then DateDiff(QQ,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MM' then DateDiff(MM,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'WK' then DateDiff(WK,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'DD' then DateDiff(DD,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'HH' then DateDiff(HH,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MI' then DateDiff(MI,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'SS' then DateDiff(SS,@R1,@R2)/@Incr End),
         cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
         cte2(N)   As (Select Top (Select M from cte0) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From cte1 a, cte1 b, cte1 c, cte1 d, cte1 e, cte1 f, cte1 g, cte1 h ),
         cte3(N,D) As (Select 0,@R1 Union All Select N,Case @Part When 'YY' then DateAdd(YY, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'QQ' then DateAdd(QQ, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'MM' then DateAdd(MM, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'WK' then DateAdd(WK, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'DD' then DateAdd(DD, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'HH' then DateAdd(HH, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'MI' then DateAdd(MI, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'SS' then DateAdd(SS, N*@Incr, @R1) End From cte2 )

    Select RetSeq = N+1
          ,RetVal = D 
     From  cte3,cte0 
     Where D<=@R2
)
/*
Max 100 million observations -- Date Parts YY QQ MM WK DD HH MI SS
Syntax:
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2020-10-01','YY',1) 
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Range-Date]('2016-01-01','2017-01-01','MM',1) 
*/
```